# c++ polynomial results, calculates only one

Tags: c++, polynomials

I am the total beginning when it comes to C++... I have to create a program which finds out the roots of the polynomial. I have compiled it etc (I changed different codes and adjusted them).. everything is fine until the polynomial has two solutions. And I have just noticed that unfortunately my program shows only one. Is there anyone who could help me with it and change in order to show the both results?
Thanks in advance!
Here's my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int root, p, q;
float numerOfRoots[100];


float algHor(int k, float x){ //Horner's algorithm
    if (k == root){
        return numerOfRoots[root];}
    else{
        return algHor(k + 1,x)* x + numerOfRoots[k];}
}


float algSTs(int j){           //Show-Trauba algorithm (function s(j))
    return (root - j) % q;
}

float algSTR(int j){           //algorithm  Show-Trauba (function r(j))
    if (j % q == 0)
        return q;
    else
        return 0;
}

float T(int i, int j, float x){ //algorithm Show-Trauba - main function
    if (x == 0)
        return numerOfRoots[j];
    else
        if (j == -1)
            return numerOfRoots[root - i - 1]* pow(x,algSTs(i + 1));
        else
    if (i == j)
        return numerOfRoots[root] * pow(x,algSTs(0));
    else
        return T(i-1, j-1, x)+T(i-1, j, x) * pow(x,algSTR(i - j));
}

float derivative(int degree, float point){
    if (point == 0)
        return T(root,degree,point);
    else return T(root,degree,point) / pow(point,degree%q);
}

main(){

    int k;
    int iteration = 100;
    float beginning, ending, results;
    p = 1;
    q = root + 1;


    cout << "\Enter the degree of the polynomial : ";
    cin >> root;
        if (root > 100){
            cout << "Too big." << endl;
        }
        if (root < 2){
            cout << "Too small";
        }

    cout << "\nNow enter the coefficients of the polynomial. Start with your greatest power .\n";
    for(k = root; k >= 0; k--){
        cout <<"a" << k << " - ";
        cin >> numerOfRoots[k];
    }

    cout << "\nEnter the beginning: ";
    cin >> beginning;
    cout << "Enter the beginning: ";
    cin >> ending;



    if (derivative(2,beginning)*algHor(0,beginning)>0){
            results = beginning;
    } else {
        results = ending;
    }

    for (k = 1; k <= iteration; k++){
        results = results - (algHor(0,results)/derivative(1,results));
        if (algHor(0,results)==0){
            break;
        }
    }


    if (algHor(0,results) == 0){
        cout << "\nReal exact root: " << setprecision(5) <<  results << endl;
    } else{
        cout << "\nReal root: "  << setprecision(5) << results << endl;
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: FYI, identifiers (such as function names) in C++ can have at least 32 characters (they can be longer, but the first 32 characters need to be unique).  I recommend practicing more readable code, like using function names such as `Horners_Algorithm` or `Algorithm_Horner`.  IMHO, these are easier to read than your naming convention.  As far as typing goes, get used to it or take a keyboarding class.

Comment: Debugger.  Use a debugger.  Please edit your post with the results of your debugging session (in text).   Please indicate the statement that is causing the issue.